# How to reformat handsontable positioning?

Tags: html, css, express, pug, handsontable

I am using handsontable to display some information in a few tables and it looks like the handsontable is covering my header text. I have them in html next to each other in the DOM. I know this is a CSS thing I have to change to ovverride it. How can I have these tables load nicely on top of each other on the same page?

Here is what it looks like. Don't worry about the data. It loads properly.

[image]

Here is some parts of my javascript for one table. there are others in here.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var containerCPhotoCounts = document.getElementById('tableCountryPhotoCounts');
   //load handsontables
            var hot = new Handsontable(containerCPhotoCounts, {
                data: countryPhotoCounts,
                minSpareRows: 0,
                columnSorting: true,
                colWidths: [200, 200, 200],
                disableVisualSelection: true,
                colHeaders: ['Country Code', 'Photo Count', 'Percent of Total'],
                columns: [
                    {data: 'country',editor: false},
                    {data: 'count',editor: false},
                    {data: 'percent', type: 'numeric',editor: false,format: '0.000 %'}
                ]
            });
}
```

Here is what my html looks like. It's jade( I'm using express).

```
h3 Photo Count By Country
#tableCountryPhotoCounts
h3 Photo Count By Date
#tableDatePhotoCounts
h3 Profile Count By Country
#tableCountryProfileCounts
h3 Photo Count By Profile
#tableProfilePhotoCounts
```

Comment: This code is not complete, even no fiddle link has been provided. I would suggest you to clear the `bottom margin` or `Add some margin` in all the tables. if you can share the code which is coming on browser then we would love to help you.

Comment: Agreed, this is as simple as adding a margin to your table divs. Just add a class to your table divs and with css do something like `margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px`